# SQL Server : FOR XML sorting control by attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

I am generating a XML file from a SQL Server query.

I have some problem about sorting elements issues.

For example, there is simple code as below.

```
<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="789"/>
    <tree-order abc="456"/>
</test>
```

As you can see tree and tree-order are different elements and I want to sort by attributes as

```
<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree-order abc="456"/>
    <tree abc="789"/>
</test>
```

like this.

Anyone has good idea to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Sorry I have detail question as below

AS is

```
 <Main>

<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="789"/>
    <tree-order abc="456"/>
</test>

<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="789"/>
    <tree-order abc="456"/>
</test>

</Main>
```

To be :

```
<Main>

<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="456"/>
    <tree-order abc="789/>
</test>

<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="456"/>
    <tree-order abc="789/>
</test>

</Main>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reorder existing xml, you can use [`XQuery`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx):

```
declare @data xml = '
<test>
    <tree abc="123"/>
    <tree abc="789"/>
    <tree-order abc="456"/>
</test>
'

select @data.query('<test>{for $i in test/* order by $i/@abc return $i}</test>')
```

Result:

```
<test>
  <tree abc="123" />
  <tree-order abc="456" />
  <tree abc="789" />
</test>
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26941)</kbd>**

**update:**

To reorder multiple nodes, you can use XQuery like this:

```
select @data.query('
    element Main {
        for $j in Main/test
            return element test {
                for $i in $j/* order by $i/@abc return $i
            }
    }
')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26968)</kbd>**

**update 2**

To order by integer values of attributes, use [`cast as <type>`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx):

```
select @data.query('
    element Main {
        for $j in Main/test
            return element test {
                for $i in $j/* order by $i/@abc cast as xs:integer?
                    return $i
            }
    }
')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26982)</kbd>**