# FOR XML multiple control by attribute in tree concept

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

I want to figure out one issue.

I already had question about simple ordering issue but I want to order more detail.
check below this link : 
[SQL Server : FOR XML sorting control by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613146/sql-server-for-xml-sorting-control-by-attribute)

I made a example case.

SQL Query.

```
select (
    select '123' AS '@id', ( 
        select 
        (
            select 'test' AS '@testid' , '20' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree') , TYPE
        ),
        (
            select 'test2' AS '@testid' , '30' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree-order') , TYPE
        ),
        (
            select 'test' AS '@testid' , '10' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree') , TYPE
        )
        FOR XML path ('Node') , TYPE
    )
    FOR XML path ('Sample') , TYPE
    ),
    (select '456' AS '@id', ( 
        select 
        (
            select 'test' AS '@testid' , '20' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree') , TYPE
        ),
        (
            select 'test2' AS '@testid' , '30' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree-order') , TYPE
        ),
        (
            select 'test' AS '@testid' , '10' AS '@order'
            FOR XML path ('tree') , TYPE
        )
        FOR XML path ('Node') , TYPE
    )
    FOR XML path ('Sample') , TYPE)
FOR XML path ('Main') , TYPE
```

Result :

```
<Main>
  <Sample id="123">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" order="20" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" order="30" />
      <tree testid="test" order="10" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
  <Sample id="456">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" order="20" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" order="30" />
      <tree testid="test" order="10" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
</Main>
```

Expected result :

```
<Main>
  <Sample id="123">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" order="10" />
      <tree testid="test" order="20" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" order="30" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
  <Sample id="456">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" order="10" />
      <tree testid="test" order="20" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" order="30" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
</Main>
```

final result :

```
<Main>
  <Sample id="123">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" />
      <tree testid="test" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
  <Sample id="456">
    <Node>
      <tree testid="test" />
      <tree testid="test" />
      <tree-order testid="test2" />
    </Node>
  </Sample>
</Main>
```

That's order by tree-order.

finally I don't want to show order information in attribute

Any one has great Idea?

Thank you for everybody who interesting to this.

Updated ----------------------------------------

Thank you every body finally I solved problem as below about order by and remove attribute issue :

```
declare @resultData xml = (select @data.query('
  element Main {
    for $s in Main/Sample
    return element Sample {
      $s/@*,
      for $n in $s/Node
      return element Node {
        for $i in $n/* 
        order by $i/@order
        return $i 
      }
    }  
  }'));

  SET @resultData.modify('delete (Main/Sample/Node/tree/@order)');
  SET @resultData.modify('delete (Main/Sample/Node/tree-order/@order)');

  select @resultData
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select @data.query('
  element Main {
    for $s in Main/Sample
    return element Sample {
      $s/@*,
      for $n in $s/Node
      return element Node {
        for $i in Node/* 
        order by $i/@order
        return 
          if ($i/self::tree)
          then element tree { $i/@testid }
          else element tree-order { $i/@testid }
        }
      }
    }  
  }')
```

Comment: That's amazing almost solved problem, thank you. I am not really familiar with XQuery.  Almost solve problem without remove attribute part. what is "node-name($I)" part ?

Comment: @clear.choi `node-name()` returns the element's `xs:QName` value. This bit of code allows you to reconstruct elements of different names (like `<tree>` and `<tree-order>`) using the same rules for their children. Also, this code should exclude the `@order` attribute: `$i/@* except $i/@order`. What problem are you having with the output?

Comment: @clear.choi Just updated a bug in the code. `<Node>` children should be ordered correctly now.

Comment: just get error message like XQuery [query()]: Only constant expressions are supported for the name expression of computed element and attribute constructors.
and just try how to used it :)

Comment: ordered was ok ~ just problem on remove attribute part

Comment: @clear.choi A few ideas: 1) try replacing `node-name($i)` with `local-name($i)`, 2) try replacing `$i/@* except $i/@order` with `$i/@testid`, 3) remove `$i/node()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, u mean return element { local-name($i) } { $i/@order } like this? still have same error...

Comment: @clear.choi No, don't output `@order`. Use `return element { local-name($i) } { $i/@testid }`. When you say error, do you mean incorrect output, or that you're actually getting an error?

Comment: Yeeeeh it's actual error like "XQuery [query()]: Only constant expressions are supported for the name expression of computed element and attribute constructors." same error as before

Comment: @clear.choi Ugh, the problem is that SQL Server doesn't support dynamically constructed element names. See updated answer for solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I solved issue already, I will update in main screen

Answer (score 2):

What's interesting to me is that in your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613146/sql-server-for-xml-sorting-control-by-attribute), you're stating that you're generating the XML as the result of a SQL query. If it were me, I'd control the ordering at that level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I already solved order control issues just remaining remove attribute after finished ordering :)

Comment: My point though is that if you solve the ordering issue another way, you get to solve this issue for free.

Comment: ok thank you for your advice finally I solved remove attribute issues by my self :)